# navigate function does not navigate to the desired page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am creating a basic React application and I have a problem with setting up the navigation. Below is a code for a `Navbar` component which once the user clicks logout button should clear the authentication context and take the user to the root page of the application. However, when I click the button it enters the handler, clears the auth context but then remains on the same page/url. Below is how Navbar and Routes are being created in my application:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const { setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext)
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = (e) => {
    setAuth(null)
    navigate("/");
    console.log("logout has been clicked");
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
      <label for="check" className="checkbtn">
        <i className="fas fa-bars">Quz</i>
      </label>
      <label className="logo">Create Your Best Team</label>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="">Messages</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/student" className="active">Profile</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="">My Group</Link></li>
        <li><Link onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

```
import Login from './components/Login'
import Student from './components/Student';
import Teacher from './components/Teacher'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { MantineProvider } from '@mantine/core';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useContext } from "react"
import RequireAuth from './customHooks/RequireAuth';
import AuthContext from "./context/AuthProvider";

function InnerApp() {
  const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext)
  return (
    <MantineProvider>
      {auth?.name ? <Navbar /> : <div></div>}
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Login />} />
        <Route exact element={<RequireAuth authID={{ id: 1 }} />}>
          <Route exact path='/teacher' element={<Teacher />} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact element={<RequireAuth authID={{ id: 2 }} />}>
          <Route exact path='/student' element={<Student />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </MantineProvider>
  );
}

export default InnerApp;
```

```
const RequireAuth = (props) => {
  const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext);
  // console.log(props.authID.id);
  // console.log(auth?.id);
  return (
    auth?.id === props.authID?.id
      ? <Outlet />
      : <div>404 Cannot go to his link</div>
  )
}

export default RequireAuth
```

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <InnerApp />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

```
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthProvider";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Login() {
    const { auth, setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [username, setUsername] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState(); 
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // Can create a pseudo authentication in here to develop
    // without the backend
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if (username === "student") {
            setAuth({name: username, id: 2});
            navigate("/student");
        } else if (username === "teacher") {
            setAuth({name: username, id: 1});
            navigate("/teacher");
        }
    }
    const handleUsernameChange = (e) => {
        setUsername(e.currentTarget.value);
    }
    const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.currentTarget.value);
    }

  return (
    <div> 
        <Input placeholder="Username" 
            onChange={handleUsernameChange}
        />
        <Input placeholder="Password"
            onChange={handlePasswordChange}
        />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

I noticed that the actual navigate command works by using `navigate(-1)`, which takes me to the previous page. However, since I will start adding more pages, going to the previous page is not sufficient and I want to redirect the client to the main page. I am assuming there is something with the `Routes`, `Route` I set up.

Comment: I see no overt issues in the code you have shared here *other than* the `Link` component used to log out is missing a `to` prop. Are there any error messages in the browser console? See if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Comment: So what I did is to add to component to="/" to the LogOut link instead of redirecting inside the handleLogout handler with navigate and it works. I start thinking that it might be somewhat of a bug with navigate which does not work inside the handlers for the Link component. However, I am not sure if this method is a good one moving forward, since as much as I know if the redirection happens before the setAuth can clear the Authenticatin context, bad things might happen.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is a missing `to` prop on the "Log Out" `Link` component.

[`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link) Type declaration:

> ```
> declare function Link(props: LinkProps): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface LinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
>     "href"
>   > {
>   to: To; // <-- Required prop!
>   preventScrollReset?: boolean;
>   relative?: "route" | "path";
>   reloadDocument?: boolean;
>   replace?: boolean;
>   state?: any;
>   unstable_viewTransition?: boolean;
> }
>
> type To = string | Partial<Path>;
>
> interface Path {
>   pathname: string;
>   search: string;
>   hash: string;
> }
> ```

I suspect there is an error being thrown in your code which prevents the navigation from working.

- Add the missing `to` prop to the "Log Out" `Link`.
- In the `handleLogout` `onClick` handler prevent the default link action from occurring, e.g. make the link *not* immediately navigate/redirect to the target path.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const { setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent default navigation action
    setAuth(null);
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
      <label for="check" className="checkbtn">
        <i className="fas fa-bars">Quz</i>
      </label>
      <label className="logo">Create Your Best Team</label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to=".">Messages</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/student" className="active">Profile</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to=".">My Group</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link
            to="/" // <-- include missing `to` prop
            onClick={handleLogout}
          >
            Log Out
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks the `BrowserRouter` provider is missing. Make sure that the `useNavigate` hook is used inside the `BrowserRouter`

The main app should look like,

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <InnerApp />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: If OP's code was not rendering a router then there would be invariant errors trying to render any of `Routes`, `Route`, `Outlet`, `Link`, and trying to use the `useNavigate` hook. In other words, it'd be obvious the router context was missing. This isn't what the OP is describing at all though.

Comment: index.js wraps App component with BrowserRouter, which wraps InnerApp component.